# Divide two integers in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to divide two integer values and store as a float.

```
void setup()
{
    lcd.begin(16, 2);

    int l1 = 5;
    int l2 = 15;
    float test = 0;
    test = (float)l1 / (float)l2;

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(test);
}
```

For some reason that I expect is fairly obvious I can't seem to store and display the correct value. 'test' variable is always set to 0.

How do I cast the integer values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be your LCD print routine, and thus the casts you have used are correct.

I tried it out on an Arduino using [serial printing](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) instead of an LCD. The expected result appears in the serial monitor (started by menu *Tools* -> *Serial Monitor*) for the complete code example below:

```
Start...

5
15
0.33
0.33333334922790
```

The last result line confirms it is a [4 byte float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) with 7-8 significant digits.

#### Complete code example

```
/********************************************************************************
 * Test out for Stack Overflow question "Divide two integers in Arduino",       *
 * <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792302/divide-two-integers-in-arduino> *
 *                                                                              *
 ********************************************************************************/

// The setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
    // Initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //The question part, modified for serial print instead of LCD.
    {
        int l1 = 5;
        int l2 = 15;
        float test = 0;
        test = (float)l1 / (float)l2;

        Serial.println("Start...");
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println(l1);
        Serial.println(l2);
        Serial.println(test);
        Serial.println(test, 14);
    }

} //setup()

void loop()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`lcd.print` doesn't know how to print a `float`, so you end up printing the integer instead.

Comment: If I remove the line with the division and just put say float test = 0.5 it prints ok

Comment: Im also running it in a simulator and the test variable is being set to 0.

Comment: @jimmyjambles Actually I may have looked at the wrong thing. Have you tried specifying the number of decimal places that you want to print?

Comment: The print command seems to be working ok as when I set the variable to something it prints correctly on the display, the problem is when I try to assign the variable to the quotient of 2 integers